# ResideMenu Android layout height wrong

Tags: java, android, residemenu

I'm using the Android [ResideMenu](https://github.com/SpecialCyCi/AndroidResideMenu) library, which has generally been good except the issue with mis-calculating the size of my main "content activity".

I've tested with several devices but it seems to be a bit off in each one, which causes a problem when i'm trying to display items from the bottom of the activity such as a snackbar or a custom pop up (see picture).

From what i've read, it could be related to the `protected boolean fitSystemWindows(Rect insets)` method in `ResideMenu.java`, but it just seems trivial to me for this to be working.

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When I used this library `ResideMenu` and I had the same problem. In the 
**ResideMenu.java** file I had a change in two functions.

Functions:

```
@Override
protected boolean fitSystemWindows(Rect insets) {

    int bottomPadding = viewActivity.getPaddingBottom() + insets.bottom;
    boolean hasBackKey = KeyCharacterMap.deviceHasKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK);
    boolean hasHomeKey = KeyCharacterMap.deviceHasKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME);

    if (!hasBackKey || !hasHomeKey) {//there's a navigation bar
        bottomPadding += getNavigationBarHeight();

    }
    this.setPadding(viewActivity.getPaddingLeft() + insets.left,
            viewActivity.getPaddingTop() + insets.top,
            viewActivity.getPaddingRight() + insets.right,
            bottomPadding);
    insets.left = insets.top = insets.right = insets.bottom = 0;
    return true;
}



private int getNavigationBarHeight() {
    Resources resources = getResources();
    int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("navigation_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    if (resourceId > 0) {
        return resources.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Many mentioned that, but it doesnt work - tested w/ emulator using `Nexus 5x API v24`

Comment: Not to mention i think that code is wrong - shouldn't it be hasBackKey || hasHomeKey (not NOT)